# Simple triple integral $ \iiint_K z\,dx\,dy\,dz $ bounded by $ x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 1, y \ge 0, z \ge 0$

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

I want to solve the following triple integral

$$ \iiint_K z\,dx\,dy\,dz $$

where K is

$$ x^2+y^2+z^2 \le 1, y \ge 0, z \ge 0$$

As far as I can tell, the bounds describe a quarter sphere.

The most inner integral:

$$ \int_0^\sqrt{1-y^2}  z\,dz $$

Now we have

$$ \iint_M \frac {1-y^2}{2} \,dydx $$
and thus
$$ \iint_L \frac {r-r^3sin^2(\phi)}{2} \,drd\phi $$

where L is (once we switch to polar coordinates)

$$ 0 \le \phi \le \pi, 0 \le r \le 1 $$

This is a simple double integral that I don't have a problem solving, but did I mess up somewhere along the road, because I keep getting the wrong answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first step should be
$$\int_{0}^{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}} z \, dz.$$

Comment: Tack Hans! Pretty obvious now that I see what is going on :)

Comment: Det var så lite! ;-)